# How can I handle ambiguous 401 unknown error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Different type of users encounter 401 unknown error.

In a hybrid office 365 environment, we have on-premise users and normal licensed users like E5.

But when I request a on-premise user or a user has no mailbox assigned

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{mail}/mailFolders/msgfolderroot
```

they both return 401 with unknown error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "2968fcd7-6a44-4c40-90b1-6f7cc66eeb6d",
            "date": "2019-04-01T03:17:34"
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like a default error returns without any information.

My question is could I determine that this kinds of user is out of service, so I could skip their data?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try loading the users licenses [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-licensedetails?view=graph-rest-1.0).

What you could also do is read the group with the on-premise/in-the-cloud users (if you have any).

And to go for a really nice solution you can even setup your hybrid environment to be available through the graph api. (which is in preview at the moment) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/hybrid-rest-support

Comment: Thank you for reply for this, it would be direction for solving this problem. But the response in server side is still indeterminable, do not know how to handle error in my system. But I am still appreciated for your reply.